# Django save field as NULL

Tags: django, database

I have form fields, I would like to keep them empty sometimes.
The problem is that save() method in the views is expecting the filed and throwing error.

**my forms:**

```
from django import forms
from cProfile import label


class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a file'
    )

    time_from = forms.DateTimeField(
        label = 'select range of time, from'
    )

    time_to = forms.DateTimeField(
        label = 'to:', required = False
    )
```

**my models:**

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
from django.utils import timezone
from celery.worker.strategy import default


class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    time_from = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    time_to = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

**my views:**

```
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'], time_from=request.POST['time_from'], time_to=request.POST['time_to'])
            newdoc.save()
```

I am trying to keep **time_to** field empty when submitting, but it is giving me this error:

> Exception Value: [u"'' value has an invalid format. It must be in
>   YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]

I think the reason is that **newdoc.save()** is expecting the DateTimeField of **time_to** format as **u'2017-05-05 12:02:02'** and getting an empty string or something like: **u''**

Answer (score 0):

You should create a ModelForm instead of a Form, and just call form.save(), doing it django will help you to manage your properties and values.

Django will create an id for your model, so you dont need to create this id

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Your Form

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document #This will link your form to your model, and django can do his job
        fields = '__all__'

    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a file'
    )

    time_from = forms.DateTimeField(
        label = 'select range of time, from'
    )

    time_to = forms.DateTimeField(
        label = 'to:', required = False
    )
```

Your View

```
def list(request):
# Handle file upload
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

If you do it, your DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES) will create an instance of Document and it will validate and store the right values.

Comment: this is great, I tried it and it worked perfectly, I need UUIDField for other stuff. Anyway, thanks